# VScodeでpython venv仮想環境のデバッガを機能させる方法

Tags: python3, vscode, debugging, python-venv

venvで仮想環境を構築し、デバッグ（F5）したいのですが、ブレイクポイントで停止せず、無視されます。
デバッグなし実行になっているのだと推測しています。

環境：
OS：Window10Pro
VScode：1.59.0
Python:3.9.6

CTRL+SHIFT+Pからインタプリタ選択を表示させると、仮想環境内のPythonインタプリタが選択肢に出てきません。表示更新しても出ません。
仕方なく、Path選択から./Scriptsフォルダ下にあるpython.exeを指定しました。

デバッガが機能するようにするにはどうすればよいでしょうか？
以前はインタプリタ選択にENV環境のPythonが選択できたのですが。
<追記>
どうやら、このリンク内容が関係していそうです。
[Python拡張機能の変更：AB Experiments](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/AB-Experiments)

下記の画像のときに、現在の仮想環境上のPythonが選択できたと記憶しています。
右上の更新ボタンを押しても変化がありません。

[image: インタープリターの選択]

setting.jsonやlaunch.jsonにpythonPathを相対パスで記述しました。
実行はできるのですが、デバッガは機能しません。
以下にjsonファイルを示します。

setting.json

```py
{
    "files.eol": "\n",
    "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
        "PATH": "${workspaceRoot}\\Scripts;${env:PATH}"
    },
    "python.pythonPath": "${workspaceRoot}\\Scripts\\pyton.exe"
}
```

launch.json

```py
{
    // IntelliSense を使用して利用可能な属性を学べます。
    // 既存の属性の説明をホバーして表示します。
    // 詳細情報は次を確認してください: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}\\Scripts\\python.exe",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: 「CTRL+SHIFT+Pからインタプリタ選択」… このとき, 何が表示されてますか？手元の環境だとワークスペース選択が出て, それを選択すると次に仮想環境選択が出ますが

Comment: インタプリタ選択時の画像を添付しました。一番上のEnter interpreter Pathからパスを入力して選択していますが、この方法だとデバッガが機能しません。実行は可能です。

Comment: `setting.json` 手元の環境では見つからないけど, Pathをセットするなら, `${workspaceFolder}\\testvenv\\Scripts\\` みたいな(仮想環境名？も含めた)指定になるのではないかと

Comment: 記述した内容で良いようです。workspaceFolderがenvフォルダとイコールなので、私の環境の場合は良いと思います。試しに、python.exeをpython2.exeなどとしてみると記述が間違っているというエラーが発生し、読み取れていることが分かっています。なお、setting.jsonのpython.pythonPathは読み取らないように変更になっているそうです。よって、launch.jsonのpythonPathが効いています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ところどころ 手元の環境と違うけれど, 問題の箇所が不明なので
とりあえず, こちらの環境の構築手順を示します

(追記)
一般的にはプロジェクトフォルダー(workspace)に移動し, venv 環境を作成するので
venv 環境をプロジェクトディレクトリーに同一化しているのが問題と思われます

最後の方に, まとめを追記しました

参考: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106071/how-can-i-set-up-a-virtual-environment-for-python-in-visual-studio-code

---

#### 環境

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:    21.04
Codename:   hirsute
```

Anaconda3 インストール済み

```
$ conda --version
conda 4.10.3
```

---

#### 準備

※ (コメントによると conda 環境は削除したとのことだが, 質問時のインタープリター選択画面によると, conda 環境は少なくとも VS Codeから認識されているので, Anaconda関係の情報として, 残しておく)

Anacondaは, 独自にパッケージ管理するので, pip など混ぜると破壊の恐れあり
仮想環境も独自に持っているので, (問題を避けるため) deactivate を行っておく

```sh
$ conda deactivate

# (手元の環境では) venv 使っていないのでインストール
# (インストール手順による動作の違いの可能性も考え 記しておく)
$ apt list python*venv*
python3-venv/hirsute,now 3.9.4-1 amd64
python3-venv/hirsute 3.9.4-1 i386
python3.10-venv/hirsute-updates,hirsute-security 3.10.0~b1-3~21.04 amd64
python3.10-venv/hirsute-updates,hirsute-security 3.10.0~b1-3~21.04 i386
python3.9-venv/hirsute-updates,hirsute-security,now 3.9.5-3~21.04 amd64
python3.9-venv/hirsute-updates,hirsute-security 3.9.5-3~21.04 i386

$ sudo apt install python3-venv
```

Python 環境を再確認   (OS側 (Anacondaではない)ことを確認)

```sh
$ python --version
Python 3.9.5
$ python
Python 3.9.5 (default, May 11 2021, 08:20:37) 
[GCC 10.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

仮想環境作成

```sh
$ cd ~/ws   # ワークスペース
$ python -m venv testvenv
```

---

#### 動作確認

ワークスペース内の Pythonソースを VS Codeで開く

左下の "Python 〜" をクリックし「インタープリターを選択」のダイアログを出す

1. "Select the workspace to set the interpreter" … で workspaceを選択
2. `'testenv': venv`  の項目(作成した venv環境)があるので選択

元の通常画面に戻るので
<kbd>F5</kbd> でデバッグ実行

---

#### ※ 追記

venv で作成した環境を workspace として登録し 扱うと, インタープリター選択の中に項目が出てこない模様
(何とかインタープリターを選択しても, activate が行われていない)

(他に何らかの手段があるかも知れないけれど)
venv での環境を認識させるには

- workspace を用意
- その下に, `python -m venv [venv環境名]` で作成

という手順を踏むのがよいでしょう

(pythonモジュール作成中の場合であっても, workspace でパス指定してるはずなので, venv で合わせて指定する必要もなさそう)

---

#### さらに追記

うまく伝わっていないようなので, 少しまとめ

質問は「VS Codeで, venv の仮想環境を認識させ, プログラムのデバッグを可能に」

回答としては

- プロジェクトディレクトリー(workspace) 直下に, ENV_DIR を作成してください … というもの

参考: (docs.python.org) [venv --- 仮想環境の作成](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/venv.html)

> ```
> ENV_DIR               A directory to create the environment in.
> ```

現状のプロジェクトディレクトリー(workspace) に手を加えるのを控えたいなら

1. どこか適当にディレクトリーを作成し workspace にして下さい
2. 次に, その直下に venv 環境のディレクトリーを作成。名前は `venv` でも, `.venv` でも適当に
3. 適当な python ソースをプロジェクトディレクトリー(workspace) 配下に置き
4. VS Code で当該 workspaceを開き, 先程のソースファイルを開いて下さい
5. 左下の "Python 〜" をクリックしインタープリターを選択してみて下さい

ENV_DIR を workspace として扱い, 認識させたい, という場合は, 別の質問として出すと良いでしょう

---

(ここから先は, 先の手順の結果によって, 追加予定だった部分)

コメントによると conda は削除したとのこと。
しかしインタープリター選択画面のスクリーンショットには condaが存在している。
もしも Anacondaを削除した後にもインタープリター選択画面に出ているようならば, 環境が壊れている可能性が考えられ, それが悪影響を及ぼしてる可能性も考えられます
(よく聞くトラブル)

その場合は, 別の質問として出してみるのもいいかも知れません

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。condaはアンインストールしました。以前までは回答いただいた内容でデバッグできていたと記憶しています。しかし、インタプリタ選択に既にenv環境が表示されないところから異なっています。そのため、解決には至りませんでした。

Comment: VMware上のUbuntu20.04において、VScodeのvenvを試してみたところ、Windowsと同じようにインタプリタ選択にはenv環境のPythonは選択肢にありませんでした。手動パスで指定して、F5実行したところデバッガが機能しました。これはWindowsと同じ手順です。したがって、Windows上のVScode特有の問題と思われます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ようやく理解できました。ENVフォルダをカレントにして実行していたからですね。サブフォルダに移動したところ、デバッガが機能しました。Ubuntu環境とは動作が異なるのですね。